# Docker DNS getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, dns, docker

I am running docker-compose with `node:4.2.1-wheezy` and `dnsdock` containers.

I have `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 172.17.42.1"` inside /etc/default/docker.

When I run `node -e "require('dns').resolve('host_name_here')"` inside my node.js container the host is resolved correctly through the 172.17.42.1 dns server.

But when I run `node -e "require('dns').lookup('host_name_here')"` it fails with `ENOTFOUND` error.

And the problem is that `http.request` uses `dns.lookup` instead of `dns.resolve`.

[The docs say](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_implementation_considerations) that `dns.lookup` calls `getaddrinfo`. And as far as I understand `getaddrinfo` caches /etc/resolv.conf and maybe it caches empty /etc/resolv.conf (but `cat /etc/resolv.conf` prints `nameserver 172.17.42.1`).

I really have no idea how to resolve this issue. What can cause such behavior?

**Update 1.**

```
docker -v
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d

docker-compose -v
docker-compose version: 1.4.2
```

**Update 2.**

I updated all things to the latest versions (docker 1.9.0, docker-compose 1.5.0 and node up to 5.0.0) but the issue still persists.

So this is the docker-compose.yml that reproduces the issue:

```yaml
dnsdock:
  image: tonistiigi/dnsdock
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock
  ports:
    - "172.17.42.1:53:53/udp"
  environment:
    - DNSDOCK_ALIAS=dns.org
node:
  image: node:5.0.0-wheezy
  command: node -e "setTimeout(function () { var dns = require('dns'); dns.resolve('dns.org', console.log.bind(console, 'resolve')); dns.lookup('dns.org', console.log.bind(console, 'lookup')); }, 5000)"
  dns: 172.17.42.1
```

You should replace `172.17.42.1` with IP of your docker0 interface. The `setTimeout(..., 5000)` is needed because `node` container may start before `dnsdock`.

This is my `docker-compose up` output:

```
Creating test_node_1
Creating test_dnsdock_1
Attaching to test_node_1, test_dnsdock_1
dnsdock_1 | 2015/11/07 09:29:44 Added service: 3653951cff40c06c04b9ab3f5d2fc94ccc19305eaac7ba1a545ce1dbab3e3e17 {test_dnsdock_1 dnsdock 172.17.42.3 -1 [dns.org]}
dnsdock_1 | 2015/11/07 09:29:44 Added service: 36577feea136bc713f77b64b2a6a9712cd509c47ca55427f6749308cc5a4b140 {test_node_1 node 172.17.42.2 -1 []}
node_1    | resolve null [ '172.17.42.3' ]
node_1    | lookup { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dns.org]
node_1    |   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
node_1    |   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
node_1    |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
node_1    |   hostname: 'dns.org' }
dnsdock_1 | 2015/11/07 09:29:49 Stopped service: 36577feea136bc713f77b64b2a6a9712cd509c47ca55427f6749308cc5a4b140
test_node_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: Can you share a docker-compose.yml that reproduces your setup?

Comment: Please also consider including an example script that reproduces this.

Answer (score 4):

For a better dns lookup, you could consider using a network overlay, as presented in "[Docker Overlay Networks: That was Easy](https://medium.com/on-docker/docker-overlay-networks-that-was-easy-8f24baebb698)"

It uses a KV (Key/Value) store bases on [Consul](http://progrium.com/blog/2014/08/20/consul-service-discovery-with-docker/), and a swarm cluster where you can register your nodes.

You can the  build an overlay network

```
eval "$(docker-machine env --swarm c0-master)"
docker network create -d overlay myStack1
```

And use it to run an image:

```
docker run -d --name web --net myStack1 nginx
docker run -itd --name shell1 --net myStack1 alpine /bin/sh
```

> Both of these containers will be attached to the same network, and be discoverable by container name (regardless of start order).
>   Further, when a container is restarted it will remain discoverable without cascading restarts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

My use case is isomorphic app. So It uses the same js on client and on frontend server.

This is the architecture I came to:
**nginx**: distributes requests between frontend and backend servers.
**dnsdock**: resolves `app.com` and `api.app.com` to nginx.
**frontend**: uses dnsdock to access backend via `api.app.com`.

And how should I implement it using docker networking? Should I get rid of nginx and dnsdock and set backend container name to `api.app.com`? What if I'll decide to use `app.com/api` instead of `api.app.com`?

Comment: @AliakseiTuzik nginx seems a good idea. dnsdock would be replaced by consul in my answer.