# What is the different between putting a separate service discovery and integrate it into the cluster machine in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, service-discovery, docker-swarm

I am having problem understanding the need of a separated service discovery server while we could register the slave node to the master node at the slave node start-up through whatever protocol. Hosting another service seem redundant to me.

Answer (score 5):

[Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/) is there to create a cluster of hosts running Docker and schedule containers across the cluster.
It does not include [service discovery](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/), which is provided by a backend service, such as etcd, consul or zookeeper.

> - The first problem: service registration and discovery is an infrastructure concern, not an application concern.
> - The second problem: implementing service registration and discovery when infrastructure and application implementation are mutually agnostic is tough.

The DockerCon makes that distinction clear [this morning (Nov. 16th, 2015)](https://twitter.com/DockerCon/status/666180701834842112), with the "Docker Stack":

[image]
<sup>(Graphics from [@laurelcomics](https://twitter.com/laurelcomics))</sup>

> Docker networking solves these problems by backing an interface (DNS) with pluggable infrastructure components that adhere to a common KV interface.

You can see [consul.io](https://consul.io/) used in:

- "[Easy routing and service discovery with Docker, Consul and nginx](https://medium.com/@ladislavGazo/easy-routing-and-service-discovery-with-docker-consul-and-nginx-acfd48e1a291)"
- "[Docker Overlay Networks: That was Easy](https://medium.com/on-docker/docker-overlay-networks-that-was-easy-8f24baebb698)"
- "[Docker DNS `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUN`D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33605656/6309)"

That means:

- **Consul** is a KV (Key/Value) store which can be plugged into Swarm in order to manage the service discovery aspect.
- **Swarm** is the access layer, which is usually the layer that contains a gateway or routing component that allows others to actually reach your services.

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*aQpT7eAmwhWItNuIi9PXFw.png]

<sup>(Image from the "[Easy routing and service discovery with Docker, Consul and nginx](https://medium.com/@ladislavGazo/easy-routing-and-service-discovery-with-docker-consul-and-nginx-acfd48e1a291)" article written by [Ladislav Gazo](https://medium.com/@ladislavGazo))</sup>

The goal is to isolate what is an infrastructure concern (Discovery service) in its own container, separate from a dev tool concern (Swarm).