# Docker localhost IP

Tags: docker, prometheus

I'm running on my laptop various containers:

```
X1C3:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4daccb82531d        prom/prometheus:latest   "/bin/prometheus -con"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp   berserk_goldstine
32c2c31e0d5f        prom/blackbox-exporter   "/bin/go-run -config."   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         0.0.0.0:9115->9115/tcp   goofy_wescoff
7490523a3bc7        prom/node-exporter       "/bin/go-run"            2 days ago          Up 2 days                                    sharp_albattani
61303633672b        prom/alertmanager        "/bin/go-run -config."   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:9093->9093/tcp   goofy_kare
89ce4f49c426        grafana/grafana          "/usr/sbin/grafana-se"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   berserk_wozniak
```

And from at least one of those containers, `prom/prometheus` I need to communicate with the other containers.

For example here is a typical configuration:

```
global:
 scrape_interval: 10s
 evaluation_interval: 10s
scrape_configs:
 - job_name: 'prometheus'
   target_groups:
    - targets:
      - localhost:9090
      - 192.168.88.161:9100
 - job_name: 'blackbox'
   metrics_path: /probe
   params:
     module: [icmp]
     target: [8.8.8.8]
   target_groups:
     - targets:
       - 192.168.88.161:9115
```

I found that I needed to specify `192.168.88.161` since localhost wouldn't work. I guess because localhost is seem to be local to that container. However the annoying aspect of `192.168.88.161` is that it's only the IP when I am at home. My **IP changes** since I move around changes all the time. So how do deal with this issue?

I speculated using `X1C3.local` but I don't see that working without bonjour discovery working across containers (doubtful!)

Comment: Can you link the container to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have started doing now is using `localhost` in my `/etc/prometheus.yml` with `docker run`'s `--net=host` option on all the services.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`docker-machine`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) and docker 1.9, the new way to reference container would be through a **[discovery service](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/)**, like, for instance **[consul](https://consul.io/)**, coupled with an inspector service like [**registrator**](http://gliderlabs.com/registrator/latest/user/quickstart/).

The other similar approach is to use **[swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/)** to manage those services (still coupled with consul)

In all cases, that implies at least two more containers (one for the consul master, one for the inspection like a swarm master or a registrator).
See "[What is the different between putting a separate service discovery and integrate it into the cluster machine in Docker Swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33723020/6309)".

The advantage over `--link` is that you can start your containers in any order, they can stop and be restarted, and they would still be visible one from another.
`--link` means the container you link to has to be started first, and it it stops and is recreated, the `--link` will not be valid anymore.

Also the discovery service approach is valid for localhost or multiple hosts. (`--link` only works locally, not accross hosts)

Comment: A discovery service sounds WAY TOO COMPLICATED. Especially if it's not using mdns (Bonjour). I'm going to try link!