# How to connect two containers which run in two different hosts?

Tags: docker

I run a web container in server A, and a DB container in server B.

How can I connect these two containers?

I only know how to connect two containers which run in same host.

Comment: You could use the new overlay network functionality that was released with docker 1.9. (See: http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/ and http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a:

- [**service discovery**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33723020/6309) which will record your containers hosts (like [Consul](http://progrium.com/blog/2014/08/20/consul-service-discovery-with-docker/), a KV -- Key/Value store)

[image: http://progrium.com/images/content/embassy/consul_layers.png]

> A good way to think of Consul is broken into 3 layers.
>   The middle layer is the actual config store, which is not that different from etcd or Zookeeper.
>   The layers above and below are pretty unique to Consul.
>
> The killer feature of Consul is its service catalog. Instead of using the key-value store to arbitrarily model your service directory as you would with etcd or Zookeeper, Consul exposes a specific API for managing services.

- a **registrator** (you can use swarm even though it is a bit overkill, or **[registrator](http://progrium.com/blog/2014/09/10/automatic-docker-service-announcement-with-registrator/)**)

> [Registrator](https://github.com/progrium/registrator) is a single, host-level service you run as a Docker container.
>   It watches for new containers, inspects them for service information, and registers them with a service registry. It also deregisters them when the container dies.
>   It has a pluggable registry system, meaning it can work with a number of service discovery systems.